# Overloading a method

Tags: java

I have came across this question in one interview.

Which of the the following methods is getting called, if we have them the same class?

```
public void me(StringBuilder str)
```

or

```
public void me(String str)
```

Why?

Comment: how are you calling it?

Comment: just for the reference , public void me(String str) is getting executed , but i want the ans why?

Comment: Depends on the parameter, btw this is not about inheritance, it's about overloading.

Comment: yeah sorry for the wrong title.. bt want to know in what scenario it will happened that method with parameter (StringBuffer) get execute

Comment: And we can't possibly tell which would be called without seeing the call. `me(new StringBuilder())` will call the first method. `me("foo")` will call the second...

Comment: @Ashish: *But what argument are you passing*? Without that information, the question is meaningless. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: i am going to pass the argument as ("ashish")

Comment: `"ashish"` is a `String` not a `StringBuilder`. So, `public void me(String str)` gets called, not `void me(StringBuilder str)`

Comment: If the parameter is a `String` the method with a `String` argument will get called. If the parameter is a `StringBuilder` then the method with the `StringBuilder` argument will get called...

Comment: This was a question interview?!

Answer (score 2):

> i am going to pass the argument as `me("ashish")`

In that case, the `public void me(String str)` will be called.

Why?  Because it is the only overload which has a formal argument type that matches the actual (static) type of the argument you are supplying.

Answer (score 0):

Which overload gets called depends on the compile-time type of the argument. This example adds a third overload that takes Object, passing a String in causes the overload that takes a String to be called when the argument is typed as a String, casting it as an Object causes the overload that takes an Object to get called:

```
public class Overload {

    public void me(StringBuilder b) {
        System.out.println("builder " + b);
    }

    public void me(String b) {
        System.out.println("string " + b);
    }

    public void me(Object o) {
        System.out.println("object " + o); 
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Overload o = new Overload();
        o.me(new StringBuilder("foo"));
        o.me("bar");
        o.me((Object)"asdf");
    }
}
```

prints out

```
builder foo
string bar
object asdf
```